# kotlin anonymous class access outer function

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to call the "gogo()" function of the SettingsActivity class. Why doesn't it work?

I once tried to access the gogo method without "this", but then the method is simply canceled without errors.
SettingsActivity.kt:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager


class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)

        val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val edt = pref.edit()
        edt.clear();
        edt.commit();
        edt.putString("signature", "secretValue");
        edt.commit();

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        createListener()

    }

    private fun createListener() {
        var listener =
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key ->
                Log.v("TTTT","RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR")
                this@SettingsActivity.gogo() //tried also: gogo()

            }
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
    }

    fun gogo(){
        Log.v("TTTT","UUUUUUUUUUUU")
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LALALA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Josef, your question is a bit unclear. What did you try to do and what didn't work? What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Move gogo() to a companion object.

[Kotlin official documentation - companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html)